# How to install pyomo compute_canonical_repn in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, pyomo

Pyomo version - 5.6.1
python - 2.7

I am totally new to Ubuntu, how can I install pyomo compute_canonical_repn?

I am getting an error while importing compute_canonical_repn

```
from pyomo.repn.compute_canonical_repn import preprocess_constraint
```

ERROR:-  No module named compute_canonical_repn

I don't find any specific installation procedures to do

FYI, the same module is working in my windows machine with pyomo version 5.2

Comment: ..pip install pyomo?

Comment: `pyomo.repn.compute_canonical_repn` does not exist in the current release of Pyomo. It seems that somehow your pip may be trying to install an oudated version of Pyomo. Can you tell us what the output of `pip install -vvv pyomo` is?

Comment: @Qi Chen thanks. version 5.6.1 got installed in Ubuntu. FYI in my other system am using pyomo 5.2 where the same module is getting imported and working fine. So if the problem is with the pyomo version, do I need to install 5.2 or is there anything I can do?

Comment: @QiChen plz find the updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment responses, this isn't an issue with the `pip install pyomo` command.
You want to be able to use `preprocess_constraint`, which was moved to `pyomo.repn.standard_repn`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked.. can you plz share the reference or any documentation link on the web

Comment: The de facto rule within the development team has been that undocumented features of the codebase may be modified without notice. I was surprised that you were using that function. I found the function again by searching the codebase for the function definition, because I vaguely remember conversations discussing relocation of parts of the expression system.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `pip install pyomo` ?

[Reference](http://www.pyomo.org/installation)

Comment: @Mahaboob Mustafa No module named compute_canonical_repn....
also plz find the updated question